# RemoteFX Hardware For Home Use

Tags: remotefx

I would like to setup Windows Server 2008 R2 using RemoteFX at home, for a couple of users to all use the server (instead of buying each user a seperate computer).

I have been trying to find what processors (Intel based) that support the SLAT that is apparently needed to run RemoteFX. I currently have a computer that has an i3 processor, but after testing it shows that it will not support it.

Does anyone know which processors from Intel do support this?

Comment: You realise that you still need some form of client to connect *to* the terminal session that's using RemoteFX, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intel states that the feature is available in all their Nehalem-based CPUs with virtualization support; namely in Core i7, Core i5, Core i3, Pentium G6950 and appropriate Xeons. It is not available in Core 2-based and earlier Intel CPUs.
>
> All Nehalem and later processes have EPT support as part of VT-x.  In the Intel product catalog, look for processors with the name format iX-XXX (e.g., i5-XXX).  Q9400 doesn't have it because it is based on Core2.

Answer (score 0):

This is [the official list of Intel processors that support RemoteFX](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology). This list is pretty thorough going back almost 10 years. To support RemoteFX, the processor only needs VT-x and EPT.

All i3 processors support RemoteFX.